# How to install adobe primetime sdk

Tags: windows, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash

I'm using Flash builder for developing flash projects.
I got some errors below.

1172: Definition com.adobe.tvsdk.* could not be found.

I think that this was happened because of not installing adobe primetime sdk.
So how can install adobe primetime sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.adobe.com/marketing-cloud/primetime/video-player-sdk.html, click download, fill in your information and start the download.